# Microsoft Durable Task Framework Not resuming from last execution point after crash

Tags: sql-server, azure, durable-task-framework

I've created a application which uses Durable task Framework.
Created TaskOrchestration called WorkflowOrchestrator, and a TaskActivity ApiCallActivity.

My orchestration is like below

```
public override async Task<long> RunTask(OrchestrationContext context, int param)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Started step 1");
    var response1 = await context.ScheduleTask<object>(typeof(ApiCallActivity), "apiRequest2");
    Console.WriteLine($"Completed step 1 with response {response1}");

    Console.WriteLine($"Started step 2");
    var response2 = await context.ScheduleTask<object>(typeof(ApiCallActivity), "apiRequest2");
    Console.WriteLine($"Completed step 2 with response {response2}");            
    return 0;
}
```

And my Task is like below

```
public sealed class ApiCallActivity : TaskActivity<string, object>
{
    public const string Identifier = "APICall";
    protected override object Execute(TaskContext context, string parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Started ApiCallActivity for {parameter}");
        try
        {
            var apiCallParameters = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ApiCallParameters>(parameter); ;
            if (apiCallParameters != null)
            {
                var client = new RestClient(apiCallParameters.BaseUrl);
                var request = new RestRequest(apiCallParameters.EndPoint, apiCallParameters.Method);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiCallParameters.Header))
                {
                    var param = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(apiCallParameters.Header);
                    if (param?.Any() == true)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in param)
                        {
                            request.AddHeader(item.Key, item.Value);
                        } 
                    }
                }

                if (apiCallParameters.Method == Method.Post && apiCallParameters.PostParameters.Any())
                {
                    var jsonBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(apiCallParameters.PostParameters);
                    request.AddParameter("application/json", jsonBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
                }

                var response = client.Execute(request);
                return response.Content;
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Parameters are not parsable");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

to check the persistence, I stopped application before starting the second api call. Up on restarting the previous instance was starting from beginning. Not from second API call. Is it how it works, Or Am I making any mistakes?
I'm using MSSQL for persistence.

on the first run Get log like this

```
Workflow Instance Started: [InstanceId: f77e4cb9-facd-4614-aaa9-287d7e765991, ExecutionId: 0a8b33bc9d044eff8b37f894c7734573]
Waiting up to 600 seconds for completion.
Started step 1
Started step 1
Completed step 1 with response
```

On second call I get log like this

```
Workflow Instance Started: [InstanceId: b9f43de2-effd-42bf-84d5-a77cf836ba87, ExecutionId: b1949afea7ad4684a4a82a5a3954bb5a]
Waiting up to 600 seconds for completion.
Started step 1
Started step 1
Completed step 1 with response
Started step 2
Started step 1
Completed step 1 with response
Started step 2
Completed step 2 with response
Task done: Completed
Press any key to quit.
Started step 1
Completed step 1 with response
Started step 2
Started step 1
Completed step 1 with response
Started step 2
Completed step 2 with response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Random in an orchestrator:

```cs
var randon = new Random();
var testVariable = randon.Next();
```

DT framework replays the method when the activity finishes and you end up with a different value, making it very confused.

In Durable Functions you would use a method on the orchestration context to get "random" numbers which are same across replays.
Not sure if DT framework has a similar utility.
Essentially you need a stable seed for the RNG.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've removed the Random from the logic, and tried again, now also I'm getting unexpected result. I"ve updated the question, can you have a look?

Comment: It's a bit hard to read the log since it's not printing the instance ID in the log. But could it be the replay that is confusing? The orchestrator method runs from the start every time it gets a result from an activity etc. But it won't actually run the activity again since it has a result in the history table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now it makes sense. I've one more doubt, please clarify if possible. What if I'm reading the list of Activity tasks from database in the orchestrator, and executing them in a for loop. Does it behave the same?

Comment: You must never do I/O in the orchestrator. If you need a list of something from the database, run an activity that returns those things. That way they will be recorded in the history table and cannot change over the replays.